# What the difference between assertion timeout and wait method

Tags: javascript, testing, timeout, assertion, testcafe

I have a test where I want to check how many times a request was triggered. I created a logger for requests and then I trigger HTTP request immediately after HTML page loading. So, a problem with t.wait(1000) test is green, but with `timeout` option that test doesn't work and I have no idea why. Where is my mistake? Thank you.

```js
const logger = RequestLogger(/http:\/\/localhost:8080/, {
  logRequestHeaders: true,
  logResponseBody: true,
  stringifyResponseBody: true,
});
```

```js
test("after first load loading triggers after end scrolling", async t => {
  await t.expect(logger.requests.length).eql(0, '', { timeout: 1000 });
  // await t.wait(1000);
  await t.expect(logger.requests.length).eql(1, '', { timeout: 7000 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/built-in-waiting-mechanisms.html#wait-mechanism-for-xhr-and-fetch-requests):

> Before TestCafe executes a test action, it waits for XHR and fetch requests to complete within 3 seconds. After TestCafe receives the responses, or the timeout exceeds, the test continues.
>
> If you expect a request to take more time, use a selector or assertion with a custom timeout to wait until the UI reflects the request completion.

Meaning that what you did in the first `expect` was to **shorten** the timeout from 3 seconds to 1 second, and maybe that is the reason for why it fails.

When you are using `await t.wait(1000)`, the test will wait 1 second before proceed to the next line of code, but the default timeout (3 seconds) remains.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the right way for that problem. I need to use promise for the expect. The right code is: ```javascript await t.expect(logger.count(record => record)).eql(0, '', { timeout: 1000 }); ```